# Securely sandboxing user scripts in a C++ program

Tags: c++, sandbox

I've been working on a personal project in C# that allows the user to execute scripts written by other users and restrict the permissions of that script. I can use .NET Code Access Security mechanisms to sandbox user scripts and make sure that they have only those permissions that the user wants to give them.

Broadly speaking, my security requirements are:

- the user should be able to restrict the untrusted script's access to only certain parts of the filesystem, including forbidding all filesystem access
- the user should be able to restrict the untrusted script's network connections to only certain IP addresses or hostnames, including forbidding all network connections
- it is okay if the user script manages to hang or terminate the host application, but the user script must not be able to circumvent the permission restrictions (i.e. denial of service is okay, breach isn't)

I'm contemplating trying to do something similar in C++, as a sort of a personal exercise. Obviously, things are more complicated when running native code directly, even if the user scripts are written in a scripting language like Lua.

The first approach I can think of is to insert my own hooks in the scripting environments standard library functions. For example, if the scripting language is Lua, instead of exposing `io.open` normally, I would have to expose a wrapper that checked the arguments against the script's permissions before passing them to the original implementation.

My concern with this approach is that it drastically increases the amount of my own code that is in charge of security and, therefore, a potential security vulnerability that I wrote myself. In other words, when working with .NET CAS, I can trust that Microsoft did its job well in the sandboxing code, as opposed to having to trust my own sandboxing code.

Are there any alternatives I'm unaware of?

Comment: Run the script in a seperate process so it runs in its own isolated address space.

Comment: I am not finally sure, but such question might probably better be asked at [SE Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). Too broad to be answered concisely here.

Comment: Use containers.

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't aware of SE Software Engineering. I don't user Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow too often, so I'm afraid I was a bit out of the loop. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I'll leave this question open just in case -- the community has the power to close it if they consider it inappropriate.

Comment: @VojislavStojkovic THX for noticing. _"I'll leave this question open just in case "_ Cross posting questions over SE sites isn't really well received. Better definitiely decide where to ask and delete posts from inappropriate sites.